# Make labels visible in code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, wysiwyg, jlabel

I'm just starting in Java and i'm stuck on something really annoying.
I'm using NetBeans IDE and i'm building a `JFrame` using drag and drop. I added two labels to my frame and renamed them (using the `WYSIWYG interface designer`).

Now I want to go in the code and change the names of the labels but they are not visible (in the code). Any idea why ? 
(I usually program in C# and with the designer the label are automatically visible in the code)

---

**Update** :

I get the following error when I try to refer to the label.

[image]

Comment: the same issue with wps, ms access, what do you expecting, put there string, JLabel is non_opaque, transparent, without Borders ..., I doubt that this question is answerable, all GUI Frameworks has own docs, tutorial, forums

Comment: sorry :-), dont't to create static methods, or don't set whatever in main method, my magic globe has low battery, something else here could be only shots to the dard, sorry i take your question as little bit funny, again  all GUI Frameworks has own docs, tutorial, forums, because there are (on this forum) preferred hand coding, not to supporting somthing from GUI framework,

Comment: O you see you solved it .. I setted something in the Main Method.. It's funny I know but it's my first java program so I had no idea. If you want you can put your comment in an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since you're new to Java and Swing, I advise you not to use drag-and-drop GUI builders. Learn to code by hand first else you may be in for a bit more of frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code they are declared in the `initComponents()` method generated by Netbeans.

If I understood you correctly, you are just looking for the JLabel variable names? If so, this is the place they would be located -- not sure if Netbeans allows you to change anything in the `initComponents()` method though. You might have to do it in the GUI editor by right clicking the label and setting the properties as you like there.

**EDIT**

That is happening because you are likely doing this in main which is a static method. I would personally create a JPanel for the labels. For example, lets say the labels are 'Titles'. So I would create a TitlePanel class to hold these JLabels (with whatever layout you'd like).

This way you can reference the class from your main and add it like so:

```
TitlePanel panel = new TitlePanel();
panel.setFirstTitle("test");    //this would be a custom method where you get the label and set it inside there
frame.add(panel);
```

On another note though, it would be wiser to learn swing via the language rather than the GUI builder simply because you might not always want to use Netbeans as the IDE but may change your preference in the future.

Answer (score 0):

they're usually named jLabel1, jLabel2.. by default, but unless you've WYSIWYGed them differently(viz changed their names in design time), there is no way to tell from the question on *how* to access them.

Comment: I said : " I added two labels to my frame *and renamed them (using the WYSIWYG interface designer)* ". 

I tried both their new names and default names (jLabel1, jLabel2). None are visible from the code. So what your're saying is that I should be seeing them without any other steps ?